# Wierd behavior on CharIndex on Nchar on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, charindex

I have faced a weird behavior, look at this query

```
declare @t nvarchar(50)
set @t = N'Hello‌'+nchar(8204)+N'World'
select charindex(nchar(8204),@t)
```

this query returns `0` as the result, while I have added `nchar(8204)` in the middle of the string.

### Update (Solved)

It is related to database collation,
I have created a new one with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS` collation and it works fine, while the former db was `Persian_100_CI_AI`

Comment: Weird, it returns `6` for me; that was on SQL Server 2008, though, and not 2012

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Weird, is it related to collation? What is your db collation?

Comment: I am using SQL 2012 and I get 6 as well.    My collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Also using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS